# onClick(View v) crash?

Tags: android, onclick

I have a `onClick()` method in another method, and crashes when the `gewinnGruen()` method is called.

Please help me know why:

```
public void gewinnGruen() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.winnergreen);
    dialog.show();
    newgame1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame1);
    newgame1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field0);
            place1 = 0;
        }
    }); 
}
```

Without the `onClick()` method it doesnt crashes and everything works.

Comment: post error message and exception stack trace

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.stupe.tictactoereloaded.GameActivity.gewinnGruen(GameActivity.java:297)
at de.stupe.tictactoereloaded.GameActivity.pruefeGewinnGruen(GameActivity.java:220)
at de.stupe.tictactoereloaded.GameActivity$1.onClick(GameActivity.java:51)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is field1??? Check if it is null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
newgame1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame1);
```

to

```
newgame1 = (Button)dialog. findViewById(R.id.newgame1);
```

You are hitting NullPointerException in this line.

And this is because, you are trying to initialize a Button in the dialog which you have created, but you didn't provide the Dialog object to the method here. So it looks into the Activity's view and returns null, since it can't find anything of that id there.

Answer (score 2):

```
newgame1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.newgame1);
                   ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with

```
public void gewinnGruen() {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.winnergreen);
        dialog.show();
        newgame1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.newgame1);
        newgame1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                field1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field0);
                place1 = 0;
            }
        }); 
    }
```